# Entity Framework v2 doesn't support sql 2000?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, ado.net, asp.net-4.0

I installed the beta 2 of Visual Studio 2010 today. I went to test out the new entity framework stuff (to see if my "issues" from v1 were fixed.).

I started adding a new connection string, but when i put in my information for sql 2000 it said "this server version is not supported. you must have Microsoft sql server 2005 or later.". Did they drop support for Sql Server 2000 in v2 of the entity framework???

Comment: Probably too late to answer this one but I thought it would be helpful if someone ended up here and could use a work-around I have tried as per my answer to a question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5703449/ef4-sql-server-2000/7262602

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Submitted a support call to microsoft and they responded:

[Entity Framework v2 doesn’t support sql 2000](https://web.archive.org/web/20110807072942/http://connect.microsoft.com:80/VisualStudio/feedback/details/499186/entity-framework-v2-doesn-t-support-sql-2000)

Here is there response:

> Thank you for posting this bug. Unfortunately, a business decision was made to no longer support SQL Server 2000 in this scenario.

So no support for sql 2000 in entity framework v2 in .net 4.0

Answer (score 3):

I have a work around that has not been disqualified yet.

[How To Use Entity Framework 4 With Visual Studio 2010 and SQL Server 2000](http://www.skonet.com/Articles_Archive/How_To_Use_Entity_Framework_4_With_Visual_Studio_2010_and_SQL_Server_2000.aspx)

Comment: I'm currently testing on this. I'll give you a feedback if it's working and post it on my blog site/notebook

Comment: @Musikero31 can you please tell me your feedback on this answer? i'm facing the same problem

Comment: Worked for me, I am using VS 2013 and connecting to SQL Server 2000

Answer (score 2):

What happens if you generate model with VS 2008 and then convert that project to VS2010 and change target framework to .Net 4.0?

Comment: That is a valid solution. We've been doing that for a few months now. Another option is creating the EDMX from a DB in Sql 2008, then change the connection string to the Sql 2000 location. It will even work when updating "update model from database". It's jut the initial EDMX creation that doesn't work. Go figure...

Comment: @Paul Lemke, @meho, could you give us more information on how to do this? I developed a site using VS2005 but production server is 2000, so need a workaround to make it work. thanks

Comment: Go into the web.config (or app.config) and locate the connection string for your entity model.  2/3 of the way through the line will be the connection info (logon, password, etc.) for the model.  Change the server name and whatever else needs to be changed. You may also need to change the ProviderToken near the top of the EDMX file (when edited with the XML editor).  Mind you, I don't know if this approach will work at all.  But it's worth a shot.

Answer (score 2):

Actually EF 4.0 supports SQL Server 2000.
It's the Database Explorer in Visual Studio 2010 that does not support SQL Server 2000.
To work around this, don't use the Database Explorer.
Instead just create an Empty model then overwrite the connection string in the config file with your SQL Server 2000 connection string.
Then you can use Update Model From Database in the EF designer to add your objects.

Comment: No, EF 4.0 won't work with SQL Server 2000. Some basic queries may happen to work but even adding a TOP clause causes my query to fail with a syntax error after pointing a working EDM to a SQL 2000 database.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this is just for the beta since the documentation still says that 2000 is supported. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896309(VS.100).aspx

You might want to submit it to connect (see FEEDBACK in Visual STudio IDE).

--added -- just want to confirm that this is happening in the EDM wizard when you are pointing to a specific database. True?

Julie Lerman

Comment: Yea, in the EDM wizard when pointing to a specific database. If i point to a sql 2005 db it works great. I'll definitely send something to connect.

Answer (score 0):

It's not just EF that doesn't support SQL Server 2000.
In Visual Studio 2010 Beta 2 the Server Explorer won't even let you add a data connection to SQL Server 2000.

Strangely, my DN Framework v1.1 code that uses SqlClient when ported to DN Framework v4 still works just fine.

I can only hope that they add MSSQL 2k support back in by the time it goes live.