# LINQ - Error running against SQL Server 2000

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Entity Framework v2 doesn't support sql 2000?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600630/entity-framework-v2-doesnt-support-sql-2000)

Running the query

```
var physicalLineItem = (from p in context.TableName
                        where p.Key == rowKey
                        select p).Single();
```

throws Error

> "{"Line 1: Incorrect syntax near
>   '('."}"

from the InnerException.

The main exception is pretty useless

> {"An error occurred while executing
>   the command definition. See the inner
>   exception for details."}

This query works on Dev with SQL Server 2005. When I send it to QA running SQL Server 2000 it fails. So I have to assume the problem is with SQL Server 2000 and LINQ. Is there a known issue? Does LINQ have a compatibility mode for 2000?