# C# - Increase method reusability

Tags: c#, .net

```
private static void ReadOrderData(string connectionString)
{
    string queryString =
        "SELECT OrderID, CustomerID FROM dbo.Orders;";

    using (SqlConnection connection =
               new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand command =
            new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
        connection.Open();

        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        // Call Read before accessing data.
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}, {1}",
                reader[0], reader[1]));
        }

        // Call Close when done reading.
        reader.Close();
    }
}
```

How can I enhance the method above to accept any `queryString`?  The problem is in the `while`.  There's a fixed # of columns I can read.  I want to be able to read any number of columns so that I can populate and return a `DataSet`.  How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SqlDataAdapter:

```
private static DataSet ReadData(string connectionString, string queryString)
{
    DataSet dataSet;
    using (SqlConnection connection =
               new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        SqlCommand command =
            new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);

        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
        adapter.Fill(dataSet);
    }

    return dataSet;
}
```

Or something like this.

Comment: +1 This looks like it will solve the problem fully.  I'll try it out.

Answer (score 3):

You're really barking up the wrong tree. You shouldn't be using "methods that accept query strings". You should raise the level of abstraction by using Entity Framework or the like.

You will then not need to use the above code because it will not exist. Those who would have called that code will do something like this:

```
var orders = from o in ordersDAL.Orders
             select new {o.OrderID, o.CustomerID};

foreach (var order in orders)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", order.OrderID, order.CustomerID);
}
```

---

Your code is badly designed in any case. Why in the world would you combine the fetching of the data with the use of it? That `while` loop should not be in that same method.

I would use something like the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6961070/c-increase-method-reusability/6961218#6961218) from obrok, but I would add the ability to use parameters.

Also, the `SqlCommand` and `SqlDataReader` both need to be within a `using` block:

```
private static void ReadOrderData(string connectionString,
  string query, Action<SqlDataReader> action)
{
  using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
  {
    using (SqlCommand command =
        new SqlCommand(query, connection)) {
    connection.Open();

    using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader()) {

    // Call Read before accessing data.
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        action(reader);
    }

    // No need to call Close when done reading.
    // reader.Close();
    } // End SqlDataReader
   } // End SqlCommand
  }
}
```

Comment: I am well aware of Entity and its benefits.  I cant use it.  My company is on SQL 2000 and will not upgrade until next year (at best).  SQL 2k does not support Entity framework.  I've tried and results are unpredictable.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600630/entity-framework-v2-doesnt-support-sql-2000

Comment: If EF won't work, what about Linq to SQL? I have used both, and while I prefer EF, the latter is vastly superior to constructing query strings. There are some limitations listed towards the bottom of the documentation : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399342.aspx

Comment: I don't know whether L2S supports unsupported versions of SQL Server (like 2000). If EF can't be used, then I would stick with raw ADO.NET until you can get on a version of SQL Server that's supported by modern software. I would not waste time with L2S in any case - you'd be going backwards in .NET code just because your SQL Server version is also backwards.

Answer (score 3):

You can do something along these lines:

```
private static void ReadOrderData(string connectionString,
  string query, Action<SqlDataReader> action)
{
  using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
  {
    SqlCommand command =
        new SqlCommand(query, connection);
    connection.Open();

    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

    // Call Read before accessing data.
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        action(reader);
    }

    // Call Close when done reading.
    reader.Close();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How I'm doing this:

(basically idea is to use `DataSet` along with `IDataAdapter`)

```
DataSet ds = null;
List<SqlParameter> spParams = ...

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
{
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(spName, connection))
    {
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.Parameters.Clear();
        command.Parameters.AddRange(spParams);
        connection.Open();

        IDbDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        da.SelectCommand = command;

        ds = new DataSet("rawData");
        da.Fill(ds);

        ds.Tables[0].TableName = "row";
        foreach (DataColumn c in ds.Tables[0].Columns)
        {
             c.ColumnMapping = MappingType.Attribute;
        }
    }
}

// here is you have DataSet flled in by data so could delegate processing up to the particular DAL client
```

Answer (score 0):

You said you tried EF, but did you try [Dapper](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/) ? looks like a simple enough ORM that should work with your database (it's raw SQL), and will avoid you most of this mapping code. Dapper is used in StackOverflow so it cannot be too bad :)

Answer (score 0):

Same suggestion as 'WorkerThread' but change the Method Signature to:

```
private static DataSet ReadOrderData(string connectionString, string queryString)
{
   // do work
}
```

Drop the following line from 'WorkerThread' example:

```
    string queryString = "SELECT OrderID, CustomerID FROM dbo.Orders;";
```

Once you have made these two changes to 'WorkerThread's' method it should be perfect for what you need.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I should have taken a minute to polish it up before posting.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [DataTable.Load](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7x8ccbsb.aspx) method. Or, for a finer level of control, check out the properties and methods on [IDataReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idatareader.aspx), such as FieldCount, GetFieldType, and GetName.